How do I change specific factor level labels while keeping the existing ones in R?
I have a factor variable in R with four levels, each associated with a label. I want to change the labels for two specific levels while keeping the labels for the other levels unchanged.
# Example data
my_data <- data.frame(
  id = 1:4,
  my_variable = factor(c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
                       labels = c("Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Date"))
)

# Initial factor levels and labels
levels(my_data$my_variable)
# [1] "Apple"  "Banana" "Cherry" "Date"

I want to change the label for Banana (level 2) to Blueberry and the label for Date (level 4) to Dragonfruit, while keeping the labels for Apple and Cherry unchanged.
I attempted to define a set of labels and apply them using mutate() and factor(). Here’s the code I tried:
# Define labels for my_variable
my_variable_labels <- c(
  `1` = "Apple",
  `2` = "Banana",
  `3` = "Cherry",
  `4` = "Date"
)

# Apply the labels to my_variable
my_data <- my_data %>%
  mutate(my_variable = factor(my_variable, 
                              levels = names(my_variable_labels), 
                              labels = my_variable_labels))

This successfully assigns the labels, but now I want to change only the labels for Banana and Date to Blueberry and Dragonfruit respectively, while keeping the labels for Apple and Cherry the same.
How can I modify my code to achieve this?

levels(x)[match(c('Banana', 'Date'), levels(x))] <- c('Blueberry', 'Dragonfruit')
